# Ignore property if it is an empty ('') string from Json/Api Response C#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, c#-4.0, json.net

Below is the json response I have currently.

```
{
   firstName: "xyz",
   lastName: "efh",
   id: 123,
   key: ''
}
```

How to ignore a property if it is an empty string like key from the above response. I know how to ignore a a property when it is null but not when it is empty.

Comment: What do you mean by "ignore"?

Comment: That's not JSON.

Comment: Your keys need to be enclosed in double quotes. And the empty value also needs to be in double quotes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To ignore empty string use [default value handling option](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_DefaultValueHandling.htm) and set property default value to empty string

```
[DefaultValue("")]
public string key { get; set; }
```

And in set `JsonSerializerSettings` as below

```
new JsonSerializerSettings 
          { DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Sample 
{
    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false, IsRequired = false)]
    public string Test { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom converter by extending Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter and override 
    void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)